# Pesquisar numa lista(API) e verificar se ele existe ou não um determinado valor digitado usando httpclient do angular

Tags: angular, typescript, api, spring-boot, httpclient

Tenho uma `API` pequena que me fornece 3 campos:

```
{
    "codproc":"197100202",
    "codassunto":"PE01005",
    "detalhe":"LICENCA PARA TRATAMENTO DE SAUDE"
}
```

No template html do angular, criei um INPUT TEXT para pesquisar nessa API se tenho o registro "codproc". Caso exista, atribuo TRUE à variável ACHOU (ACHOU=true).

Estou usando no component(ts) o seguinte código:

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/processosistra/')
  .subscribe(Resposta => {
      console.log(Response);
   });
```

Isso lista todos os registros da `API`, mas não sei como testar se o valor que digitei existe no campo `CODPROC` nessa lista .

Observação: `CODPROC` é `id`.

Como posso fazer essa verificação?

Answer (score 0):

É possível usar `path params` e/ou `query params`.

Em resumo o `path params` deve ser usado em rotas onde é necessário identificar um caminho especifico. Um ótimo exemplo são rotas GetById que retornam o item que você precisa.

```
buscarProcessos(empresaId: any, projetoId: any): Observable<any[]> {
  let URLAPI = 'http://localhost:8080/empresa/'+ empresaId+
 '/projeto/'+ projetoId + '/processosistra/'
  return  this.http.get<any[]>(this.URLAPI );
}
```

Já o `query params` é usado comumente para parâmetros opcionais nas requisições o mesmo é mais relacionado a buscas, filtros, e ordenações. A classe [`HttpParams`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams) contem a documentação com mais detalhes de como enviar uma request com parâmetros.

```
buscarProcessos(search: any): Observable<any[]> {
  var URLAPI = 'http://localhost:8080/processosistra/'
  let params = new HttpParams();
  params = params.append('search', search);
  return  this.http.get<any[]>(URLAPI , { params });
}
```

caso não queira usa-la também é possível construir a url a mão segundo o formato abaixo.

```
buscarProcessos(search: any, valor2: any): Observable<any[]> {
  let URLAPI = 'http://localhost:8080/processosistra/?search='+ search + '&chave2='+ valor2
  return  this.http.get<any[]>(this.URLAPI );
}
```

obs: Lembrando que no caso de `query params` é possível enviar quanto parâmetros desejar

Para mais informações consulte:
[When do I use path params vs. query params in a RESTful API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30967822/when-do-i-use-path-params-vs-query-params-in-a-restful-api)

Comment: Acho que o que ele quer é filtrar o array (acho que é um array) retornado pela API e não que a API já venha filtrada!

Comment: se esse for o caso vou mudar a minha resposta quando ele confirmar algo. de todo modo o melhor meio ainda é fazer um filtro na api que consumira menos processamento do `client side` da aplicação. por exemplo se ele tem 50 ou 100 items é tranquilo fazer esse filtro. mas e quando for 20000, 100000 fica complicado travar o navegador do usuário por alguns segundos pra fazer um filtro.

Comment: Gente, obrigado pela ajuda de vocês que foi de grande valor! Depois de ler suas instruções, revisei meu findbyid e vi que estava errado. Está tudo funcionando agora!